emacs initialisation files
I'm aware of being able to start emacs with a specific init.el, but I'm trying find a way of having my normal emacs configuration which is in ~/.emacs.d separate from my doom configuration which is in ~/.config/emacs.
Doom has init.el in ~/.config/doom and early-init.el in ~/.config/emacs so when I specify --load= emacs knows the location of the required init.el but grabs early-init.el from the default location.
What can I do to enable the use of both configurations as and when I choose to?

Doom uses by default two folders, e.g. ~/.emacs.d and ~/.doom.d, the first one is for all emacs modules, the second is for user configurations. You should have these two, or both in ~/.config.

And the file early-init.el should be present only in emacs, not both.

man emacs has --init-directory=directory

Start emacs with user-emacs-directory set to directory.

This question says it is available in Emacs 29+. Does this help?
